# JS is failing in IE8 due to strange error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a large javaScript file, managing all kinds of UI elements. It works perfectly in FF, chrome and Safari, but in IE it falls over.

I loaded it into IE8 to use the JS debugger, and it points to this line:

```
var myFooter = false;
```

and claims: `Object doesn't support this property or method`.

---

**Edit**

It seems to have a problem with this function, specifically the `var` declaration

```
function live_test(){
    var active_project;
    active_project = $("div.project_holder.active");
    $("#circles img.link.active").removeClass('active');
    $("#circles img.link").each(function(){

        if ($(this).data('project')[0] == active_project[0]){
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post more code... How about the lines preceding and following that line?

Comment: So what happens if you remove that line and instead use:  `var active_project = $("div.project_holder.active");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved by changing each `$` for `jQuery`

As it lives in Wordpress, it had noConlict turned on.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Your solution is usually only needed when there's a conflict with `$` from another library.  Also, please "accept" the answer if it is indeed the solution.

Answer (score 3):

check to see if you have an extra comma or something

Throw your JS code in jslint.com

Comment: jslint or jshint - the latter will give you more useful results faster.

Comment: This is a great suggestion but it's more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: great tip, cheers, but code is now clean, and I am still having some problems!! Have edited question now I have been able to be more specific.